# SQL Server Connectivity Test

Tags: troubleshooting, connection, sql-server

Many times people around me fail to connect to SQL Server from other Non-Microsoft Applications.

Assuming that there is no SQL Server Client installed, what are the different ways we can troubleshoot the connectivity test?

I know of following 2 tests:
1) Telnet to SQL Server IP with port 1433.
2) Every Windows PC comes with SQL Server ODBC Driver.  Goto Control Panel and setup a test ODBC connection for SQL Server and perform the connectivity Test.

Please add any other ways you would troubleshoot such problem.

Answer (score 3):

When the SQL server port and IP address are known,
the easiest method would be "**`TELNET server_ip port`**" like you have stated in your question.

To analyze what happens to the connect attempt,
you could add in **Wireshark** or **tcpdump** if available.
That will help you diagnose what is going wrong when the telnet cannot connect.

Sometimes looking at the **`netstat`** and **`arp`** results also helps.

Typical problems are,

1. Firewall rules

   - proxy settings and details
   - network connectivity problems (temporary or otherwise)
   - server failure (also happens)